# Securing encryption key - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, operating-system, key

We have a situation where we have to secure our encryption key (For AES Encryption of cookies) which is hardcoded at the front end (Android).

Things we can't do:

1. Can't use proguard
2. Can't use minifyEnabled
3. Can't use Enigma (Library)
4. Can't use KeyStore/SharePreferences/ContentProviders/Local Storage
5. Can't take the key from API
6. Can't use NDK

(Above methods are vulnerable or not possible to use as per our environment)

I am aware that this is not the best practice to have this mechanism, but it's a situation the only way is to keep the Keys hardcoded at the front end.

Please suggest a solution for this scenario.

```
    private const val secretKey = "THISISMYKEY="


    private const val salt = "THISISMYSALT="

   
    private const val iv = "THISISYOURIV=="
```

Comment: What you describe is simply the result of bad crypto design, use asymmetric croptography, then including the key in your app wouldn't be a security risk.

Comment: As i mentioned, i am aware that this is bad practice, but i have to do it in this way only

Comment: If you use encrypted cookies and the AES key is in the Android app, then the server is also running inside the Android app? because usually encrypted cookies are used to be able to store data on client side without the possibility for the users to read or modify them.